# how to change location icon on google maps (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter

I use a pretty close zoom on my google maps. So close that the blue device location icon and its 'border' casts a blue shade over the area. Is there a way to customize and remove that? Thanks!

Edit: What I found out about blue round shade around the device's marker was the diameter for location accuracy. It's wider when map can't figure out an accurate location and just predicts it to be somewhere in that large blue area.

Comment: can you show what have you done till now?

Comment: @AlanBosco i just called a map widget, I was looking if there is a parameter where I can remove my device's location marker circular "border" in the map the (default blue dot)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

```
class MapDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const MapDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 /*Controller*/
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  /*Variable declaration*/
  bool customFlag = false;
  BitmapDescriptor customIcon1;


 /*Custom Marker for Maps*/
  createMarker(context) {
    if (customIcon1 == null) {
      ImageConfiguration configuration = createLocalImageConfiguration(context);
      BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(configuration, ImagePaths.dcGlobe) /* ImagePaths.dcGlobe i san asset image */
          .then((icon) {
        customIcon1 = icon;
      });
    }
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    createMarker(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          LocationMaps(
            mapController: mapController,
            customFlag: customFlag,
            customIcon1: customIcon1,
            longitudeValues: 85,
            latitudeValues: 12.0,
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LocationMaps extends StatelessWidget {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  bool customFlag;
  final BitmapDescriptor customIcon1;
  final longitudeValues;
  final latitudeValues;

  LocationMaps({
    Key key,
    this.mapController,
    this.customFlag,
    this.customIcon1,
    this.longitudeValues,
    this.latitudeValues,
  }) : super(key: key);

  double locationLatitude = 0.0;
  double locationLongitude = 0.0;

  LatLng _center;
  List<Marker> _markers = <Marker>[];

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    locationLatitude = double.parse(latitudeValues);
    locationLongitude = double.parse(longitudeValues);
    _center = LatLng(locationLatitude, locationLongitude);
    _markers.add(Marker(
        icon: customFlag == true ? customIcon1 : null,
        markerId: MarkerId(''),
        position: LatLng(locationLatitude, locationLongitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: '')));
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      child: Container(
        color: AppColors.creamColor,
        width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child: Container(
                width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(120.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: GoogleMap(
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: (Platform.isAndroid) ? true : false,
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: _center,
                    zoom: 13.0,
                  ),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If  I understand this correctly, do you mean that replacing  it with a custom marker will remove that border?

Comment: Instead of location marker, you can add your custom images